# JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed: can't verify my Webtoken

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ionic-framework, jwt

I added Tokens to my actual project but I have a problem with decoding them:

I use the following Method to decode the token:

```
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
console.log(req.headers);
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers.authorization));
if(!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request!');
} 
let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
console.log(token);
if(token === 'null') {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request!');
}
let payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey');
if(!payload){
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request!');
}
req.userId = payload.subject;
next();
}
```

The intercept Method:

```
  intercept(req, next) {
    let storageService = this.injector.get(StorageService);
    let token = '';
    storageService.get(AuthConstants.AUTH).then(res => {
      console.log("res: " + res + '\ntype: ' + typeof(res));
      
      token = res;     
    });
    
    let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
    
    return next.handle(tokenizedReq);
  }
}
```

EDIT:

the storage service:

```
async store(storageKey: string, value: any) {

    const encryptedValue = btoa(escape(JSON.stringify(value)));

    await Storage.set({
      key: storageKey,
      value: encryptedValue
    });
  }

  async get(storageKey: string) {

    const res = await Storage.get({ key: storageKey })

    if(res.value) {
      return JSON.parse(unescape(atob(res.value)));
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Now there is the following Problem: res has the value of the token and assigns it to the "token". BUT authorization is done with token= ''. I think this is because the storageService.get() function is async. How can I tell my code to wait for the data beeing assigned to the token before doing the req.clone?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**server.js**

```js
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header('Authorization');
  if (!token) return res.status(401).send('Access Denied!');
  
  try {
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey');
    req.user = verified;
  }
  catch(err) {
   res.status(400).send('Invalid Token!');
  }
}
```

auth.iterceptor.ts

```js
 let token = this.authService.getToken();
 const updatedRequest = request.clone({
   headers: request.headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
 });
```

Comment: There is an error: `throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

And I am testing the method with a valid token, but it returns the 'invalid token'

Comment: I added an interceptor sample too. check this one

Comment: I found the problem, I added it in my question above.